# On my previous workplace, my Windows PC can be used by more than 20 people using their own user account. How is this done?

Tags: windows-10

My old office provided me a personal windows PC, but it can be used by pretty much every other employee that has a registered user account. It is the same case with everyone else's PC. I'm curious how is this done. I imagine there's a way to do this aside from the admin registering every employee user account on each PC. That would kind of inefficient and time consuming.

Comment: The machine would have been joined to the company domain. So when connected to the domain network, any user can authenticate and log in. The users are not stored on the computer. They are stored on the domain controller within active directory. When an authorised user tries to log in on the domain connected machine, only then does the user profile create itself locally on that machine.

Comment: @Mastaxx, why not just make that an answer? It's clear and informative.

Comment: Just figured this was more of a conversational topic rather than helping someone find a solution to a problem. But you're right it is technically "the answer" haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about this being automated. The specific solution for this is an **Active Directory** domain created on a company server called a **Domain Controller**.

Your PC doesn't use **local accounts** (they're usually blocked in domains), instead it sends credentials to a controller, and if they're correct, it either:

- Creates local storage for that user, as it would normally do on a "separate" PC, only automatically.
- Download (and later synchronize) the user profile from the server, using the **Roaming User Profiles** functionality.

As long as your PC is connected to the network (either directly to the corporate network or via VPN), it can do this live. If it's not connected, it will keep existing users in cache for some time. (Yes, this means that you can lose access to your own computer if you are disconnected long enough. In such a case you would need to reconnect or use one of the tricks to restore the local account).

As for "Is it the same case with other PCs":

- Generally yes. Each PC and each domain user is assigned accounts in the domain and all this information is stored in a centralised database.
- However, one of the main reasons for using domains is access control. The domain administrator can set up **Security Groups** and **GPO Rules** to restrict who can access what computer and even what exact services they can use.

This can end up with this type of access list, for example:

- You can log on to your computer and use anything on it, but without administrator rights.
- IT support can log on to your computer with administrator rights (still not full, but let's not go into detail)
- Your colleagues in the same department can log on to your computer and use most applications, but they can't see your documents.
- Anyone else in your company can log on to your computer, but can only use a limited list of applications and only their private documents.
- Some services (special programs that work in the background) are allowed to use your computer with special rights.
- *Final note:* This list is a rather complicated example. In practice it usually ends with "normal users can log in or not depending on the department, additionally support has admin rights" ;)

Answer (score 1):

The machine would have been joined to the company domain. So when connected to the domain network, any domain user can authenticate and log in. The users are not stored on the computer. They are stored on the domain controller within active directory. When an authorised user tries to log in on the domain connected machine, only then does the domain user profile create itself locally on that machine.

Answer (score -1):

Windows uses a [domain type infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain) wherein a Domain Controller (A windows server can be assigned this role) can handle management of users and assets within that (sub) domain.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with more details.